# ng-bootstrap modal: open it via typescript

Tags: html, angular, modal-dialog, frontend, ng-bootstrap

I'm having problems, I'd like help opening a mode from the component.
I would like to open the modal when the user has been verified in a form.

.component.html

```
<ng-template #modalExample let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
/** Modal body **/
</ng-template>

<form (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && signin()" #f="ngForm" class="">
/** Buttons, labels, buttons **/ 
</form>
```

.component.ts

```
signin() { 
/**Calling backend**/ 
this.modalService( *REFERENCE TO MODAL HERE* )  
}
```

I've tried using

```
@ViewChild('modalExample') modalExample: ElementRef
this.modalService.open(this.modalExample);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `open` method expects either a component or a template ref to function correctly, and ViewChild gives you a TemplateRef by default. To resolve this change your ViewChild declaration to:

```
@ViewChild('modalExample', {read: TemplateRef}) modalExample: TemplateRef<any>;
```

and pass that through to `this.modalService.open(this.modalExample)` when you want to open the modal and that should work.

The [Bootstrap site](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) has various examples you can look to see how to open the modal.

Comment: It works very well, but i receive an exception in console: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched: true'. Current value: 'ng-untouched: false'."
What can i do?